# Error en el procedimiento de almacenado

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Estoy teniendo un problema al momento de crear el delimiter ya que me aparece que tengo una sintaxis incorrecta a la hora de ejecutarlo.

```
    delimiter %%

    create procedure sel_sa(
    @cedula_sa varchar(20))
    as
    begin
    select * from superadmin where @cedula_sa = cedula_sa;
    end%%
```

Pero al dar la ejecución me da un error de que la sintaxis esta errónea desde %, quisiera ayuda se lo agradecería.

Comment: porque utilizas delimiter, no puede simplemente escribir el procedimiento?

Comment: Lo utilizo mas que todo porque así me lo enseñaron hace como dos años, y lo recordaba así, entonces no es necesario hacer el delimiter?

Comment: no es necesario delimiter   create procedure sel_sa(
    @ cedula_sa varchar(20))
    as
    begin
    select * from superadmin where @ cedula_sa = cedula_sa;

Comment: Si mal no estoy (Perdonen mi ignorancia si es asi) el Delimiter como tal no existe en Sql Server, al menos en lo que llevo de vida no lo he visto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no se para que usas ese Delimiter, hice la instrucción de la siguiente manera y ejecuto bien, espero sirva

```
use 'Nombre de BD'
go
CREATE PROCEDURE sel_sa
@cedula_sa varchar(20)
as
begin
select * from core.IPS where @cedula_sa = cedula_sa;
end
```

Saludos.

Comment: Si excelente respuesta me funciono también.